# debug function called within "while-no-input"

Tags: debugging, emacs

I try to debug a function `compute` that is called within the context of `while-no-input`.

```
(while-no-input (compute arg1 arg2))
```

Instrumenting `compute` for edebug and pressing the keys of the edebug have it jump outside the `computation` and this spoils the execution of the debugger in an ugly way.

I do not know whether it is possible to debug the `compute` without cutting `while-no-input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. `while-no-input` doesn't care whether the input comes from typing while in the debugger.

To debug in a context like this, I'd insert calls to `message` in the code you want to debug, echoing to buffer `*Messages*` any intermediate values or other info that helps.

`while-no-input` cares only about input, not output (e.g. calls to `message`).